# Teacher told me this was wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

So my teacher gave me wrong on the code down below. He said its not possible that it could work. When i asked what was wrong he just said it was obvious. I really cant see what the problem is. I really need your help since my teacher wont help me.

The only section he told me was wrong:

```
create or replace trigger aifer_deposit
after update or insert
of amount
on deposit
begin
update account
set saldo = saldo + (select amount from deposit);
end;
```

Anybody know the problem?

Comment: Have you tried your code? Did it work or not? Make sure to insert several rows into each table.

Comment: I suspect you need for each row -trigger

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables; a description of what the trigger is intended to do (we can't tell you what is wrong if you don't tell us what is expected); and what errors you get.

Comment: A trigger in Oracle without `:new` or `:old` is highly suspicious.

Comment: @GordonLinoff does a statement-level trigger have `:new` and `:old`?

Answer (score 0):

*Please* check the documentation for syntax: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B

Here's what I see, just in terms of syntax:

1. You are missing the "for each row" clause
2. The "on column" clause must follow the "on update" not "insert"
3. A trigger cannot reference the table it is attached to in a query. You will get a "mutating table" error when the trigger executes. Use a built-in bind variable to reference the new value of the amount in the row.

Try this:

```
create or replace trigger aifer_deposit
after insert or update of amount
on deposit for each row
begin
    update account set saldo = saldo + :new.amount;
end;
```

That said, I see issues with logic here, too. Without a primary key, your update will update *every row* of the account table to the new value, not just the account that was updated. Also, in this configuration what happens when a deposit is updated? The value of saldo is always increased by the new value, not the change in the value: the value of saldo (which I take to be the account balance) will be wildly inaccurate. You need to use a compound trigger to differentiate the logic between inserts and updates.

Comment: It does not say it shall be a **ROW-LEVEL** Trigger! Thus: `for each row` might not be desired. The "mutating table" error appear only on row-level triggers.

Comment: Then the logic would make even less sense, as the subquery would return multiple rows and fail. Even if it was a sum or other aggregate, it would update every value of saldo on every account to the new aggregate value for all deposits. Any way you cut it, this trigger is seriously flawed.

Answer (score 0):

From syntax the trigger is working. However, logically there a some failures.

The update

```
update account set saldo = saldo + (select amount from deposit);
```

will most likely fail, because `(select amount from deposit)` requires to return **exactly** one row, which is most likely not the case. Also this statement will update **all** rows at table `ACCOUNT` which is most likely not desired either.

Most likely you ask for a row-level trigger. In this case you miss the `FOR EACH ROW` clause. But then you must not use `select amount from deposit`, you cannot select the base table within a trigger, this will raise the famous "mutating table" error.

So, first asked your teacher about the desired logic, then we can discuss the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the logic that you would want is:

```
    update account
        set saldo = saldo + coalesce(:new.amount, 0) - coalesce(:old.amount, 0);
```

That is, subtract out the old value and add in the new.  That is how you maintain a cumulative sum.